# Detecting Hebrew Characters in PHP Strings

Tags: php, string, utf-8, hebrew

In PHP, is there a known safe/reliable way to

1. Detect, generically, a hebrew character that's in a string of plain english characters.
2. Replace that character with something

I know I could, for a set of specific characters, use `mb_ereg_replace` to replace specific characters.  However, I'm interested in being able to scan a string that might contain *any* hebrew character, and then replace it with things.

That is, I might have two strings like this

```
<?php
    $string1 = "Look at this hebrew character: חַ. Isn't it great?";
    $string2 = "Look at this other hebrew character: יַָ. It is also great?";
```

I want a single function that would give me the following strings

```
Look at this hebrew character: \texthebrew{ח}. Isn't it great?
Look at this other hebrew character: \texthebrew{י}. It is also great?
```

In theory I know I could scan the string for characters in [the hebrew UTF-8 range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet) and detect those, **but** how character encoding on strings works in PHP has always been a little hazy for me, and I'd rather use a proven/known solution if such a thing exists.

Comment: Ensure the string is UTF-8 encoded and then work on the unicode properties. You can also normalize it first.

Comment: Thanks for the time/attention @hakre - that's sort of of what I was getting at with * In theory I know I could scan the string for characters in the hebrew UTF-8 range and detect those*.  However, as that smells like one of those tasks with a number of unknown unknowns, I'd prefer some proven science before I go off and reinvent another wheel.

Comment: I left you an answer how this can be done with the mb_* family of functions. The Unicode support is working, you should provide strings encoded as UTF-8. Use preg_match to validate if the string is properly UTF-8 encoded, mb_ereg_* has problems with invalid UTF-8 (not detecting it as invalid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**mb_ereg_replace_callback** function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace-callback.php) is useful in your case. The [regular expression dialect](https://github.com/geoffgarside/oniguruma/blob/master/Syntax.txt) has support for named properties, the *Hebrew* property specifically. That is [Hewbrew Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_(Unicode_block)) (`IntlChar::BLOCK_CODE_HEBREW`).

All you need to do is to mask the Hebrew segments:

```
mbregex_encoding('utf-8');
var_dump(mb_ereg_replace_callback('\p{Hebrew}+', function($matches) {
    return vsprintf('\texthebrew{%s}', $matches);
}, $subject));
```

Output:

```
string(65) "Look at this hebrew character: \texthebrew{חַ}. Isn't it great?"
```

As the output shows, the four bytes with the two code-points are properly wrapped in one segment.

I don't know of any other way to do that in PHP with that little code.

Answer (score 0):

To detect if the string has Hebrew text, use the boolean function mb_ereg_match:

```
mb_ereg_match('\p{Hebrew}+', $stringtosearch);
```